# Sorting Words from a input text depending on how many times it was repeated?

Tags: c++, class, sorting, vector

I am trying to make a Program that reads an input text from the user and then  prints out each word and how many times it was repeated in a sorted order. ( the input is separated by white spaces and it can hold punctuation but no new lines)

Example of Input : **I am a good programmer and I love C language**.

output should be :

- **a : 2 times

                     I : 1 time

                   am : 1 time

                   good : 1 time**

  ... and so on.

** for the input I used a vector and classes  but i don't know why i can't push several items in it.

```
class word {public:
word();
void set_data(string data_value);
void printing_data();
void counter_addition();
int count;
string data;};
```

---

```
int main(){ /*creating vecotr called items of list class type*/
vector<word>items;

/*creating a variable of list class type which is used to push data into the vector*/

word *element;

/*Reading the input text seperated by white spaces*/
int size = 0;
string text;

cout << "Enter the text: " << endl;
getline(cin, text);

size = text.length();
int left_space = -1;
int right_space = 0;
string Sub_String;

/*main loop for constructing substring of words and then manipulating them*/

for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
{

    /*splitting the string into words*/
    if (isspace(text[i]) || ispunct(text[i]))
    {
        right_space = i;

        Sub_String = text.substr(left_space + 1, right_space - left_space - 1);
        /*for first word just push it*/

        if (left_space == -1)
        {
            element = new word();
            element->set_data(Sub_String);
            items.push_back(*element);

        }

        else
        {
            /*compare to vector's data */
            for (int j = 0; j < items.size(); j++)
            {
                if (Sub_String == items[j].data)
                {
                    items[j].count = items[j].count + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    element = new word();
                    element->set_data(Sub_String);
                    items.push_back(*element);
                }

            }
        }
            left_space = right_space;
    }
```

---

if the words are the same the output is correct .

> input : Life life life life

---

> output: Life repeated:4

Please help me through this I am new to programming .

Comment: Basically, iterate over each word(2 for loops) and compare the words using (strcmp) and increment counter. Include structs too as it will make the job easier ar store string and repeat in struct instead of making new variables every time. Also because you are new to programming don't aim for efficiency, aim for right code. So store user input in a file because it will be easier to process than using substrings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the string values and count into std::map< std::string, int > and for each word, check if it is already in the map. If it is there, increment the count. In opposite case insert it with count = 1